# olap4j errors after migrating to WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, olap4j

Used olap4j 1.2.0 and olap4j-xmla 1.2.0
With JBoss 5.1 no errors, when app running on WildFly see next errors in logs:

```
org.olap4j.OlapException: Internal error: hierarchy '[dimP].[ID P]' not found in cube 'LCube'
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: recursive population
```

Same olap4j libs, same connection setting, same cube. Furthermore, month ago all works perfectly with WildFly with same libs and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing all connections fixed problem.